# Defining an expression to insert into NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, variational-calculus

Consider the follwoing Code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

x[t_] := {{s[t] Cos[u[t]] + b/2 Sin[u[t]]}, {-s[t] Sin[u[t]] + 
    b/2 Cos[u[t]]}}

T[t_] = Simplify[1/2 (m) Flatten[x'[t]].Flatten[x'[t]]] + 
  1/2 (1/12 m (L^2 + b^2) + m s[t]^2) u'[t]^2

L[t_] = Simplify[T[t] + m g (s[t] Sin[u[t]] + b/2 Cos[u[t]])]


<< VariationalMethods`

eoms[t_] := Simplify[VariationalD[L[t], s[t], t]]

eomu[t_] := Simplify[VariationalD[L[t], u[t], t]]

solution = 
  With[{m = 0.1, L = 0.1, g = 9.81, b = 0.02}, 
   First@NDSolve[{eoms[t] == 0, eomu[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, s[0] == 0, 
      s'[0] == 0.3, u'[0] == 0}, {u, s}, {t, 0, 10}]];
```

Which gives me the error:

```
NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {0.3,-((0. +0.0010249 b g)/(7.00286*10^-7+b^2+L^2)),0.,-((12 (0. -0.000170817 g))/(7.00286*10^-7+b^2+L^2))} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {t,s[t],(s^\[Prime])[t],u[t],(u^\[Prime])[t]} = {0.000569391,0.000170817,0.3,0.,0.}.
```

It seems that this error comes from my definition of `eomu` and `eoms` (if I insert the results of the two `Simplify` functions directly into `NDSolve` it works just fine).
Can somebody explain to me why this happens and how one could define `eomu` and `eoms` properly so that it works? (I probably need to make sure that they are not only functions of `t` but also of `u` and `s` but I don't really understand how once could do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `L` as well as `L[t]` is a bad idea. I will change `L[t]` to `U[t]`. Then, using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) instead of [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) does what you want:

```
x[t_]:={{s[t] Cos[u[t]]+b/2 Sin[u[t]]},{-s[t] Sin[u[t]]+b/2 Cos[u[t]]}}

T[t_]=Simplify[1/2 (m) Flatten[x'[t]].Flatten[x'[t]]]+1/2 (1/12 m (L^2+b^2)+m s[t]^2) u'[t]^2;

U[t_]=Simplify[T[t]+m g (s[t] Sin[u[t]]+b/2 Cos[u[t]])];

<<VariationalMethods`

eoms[t_]:=Simplify[VariationalD[U[t],s[t],t]]

eomu[t_]:=Simplify[VariationalD[U[t],u[t],t]]

solution = Block[{m=0.1,L=0.1,g=9.81,b=0.02},
    NDSolve[{eoms[t]==0,eomu[t]==0,u[0]==0,s[0]==0,s'[0]==0.3,u'[0]==0},{u,s},{t,0,10}]
]
```

> {{u->InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,10.}}
>   Output: scalar
>   ],
>   s->InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.,10.}}
>   Output: scalar
>   ]}}